# Load a line from <script> on specific page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a situation where I need to load the "Purchase" event inside this script only on certain pages. I'm adding it to `header.php` and need to load FB Pixel on all pages, but that one event only on the order confirmation page. How would I load only that one link inside of this script just based on the URI?

```
<script>

 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s) {
   if(f.fbq) return;
   n=f.fbq=function() {
     n.callMethod? n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)
   }; 
   if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
   n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0; 
   t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)} 
   (window,document,'script', 
   'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'); 

   fbq('init', "xxxxx"); 

   fbq('track', 'PageView'); 

   fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '0.00', currency: 'GBP'});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be loading scripts in your `header.php` file, they should be enqueued in your `functions.php` file using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook. It will make your life many times easier later. I'm still cleaning up past-me's mistakes of loading scripts directly into the header and footer files.

First, you should save the first part of your script and upload it to your theme's `/js` folder, name it something simple like "facebook-tracking.js"

**facebook-tracking.js**:

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s) {
  if(f.fbq) return;
  n=f.fbq=function() {
    n.callMethod? n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)
  }; 
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0; 
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)} 
  (window,document,'script', 
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'); 

fbq('init', "xxxxx"); 

fbq('track', 'PageView');
```

To enqueue that properly, in your `functions.php` you *would* add the following (but hold on):

```
function enqueue_fb_tracking() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'fb-tracking-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/facebook-tracking.js', array(), '1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_fb_tracking' );
```

**However** you need to extend your script on certain pages. Luckily WP has a function for that called [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/). So we can flavor that in there just as well, using [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) to only load it on the pages you want.

```
function enqueue_fb_tracking() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fb-tracking-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/facebook-tracking.js', array(), '1.0.0' );

    $purchase_pages = array(
        'checkout',
        'some-other-page'
    );

    if( is_page( $purchase_pages ) ){
        wp_add_inline_script( 'fb-tracking-js', "fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '0.00', currency: 'GBP'});" );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_fb_tracking' );
```

Just put the page titles, slugs, or ID's you want it to track the "Purchase" action on in the `$purchase_pages` array.

Comment: Thanks @Xhynk! Great answer. For WooCommerce, would "checkout" be enough in the array? Also, my url slug is `/checkout/order-received/11384/` where the last `11384` is randomly generated. Would that work with your suggestion?

Comment: I'm no longer at my computer so I'm not entirely sure what it would be. If you look at the `<body class` with inspect element you should be able to see like a `page-id-1234` or `page-template...`. if there's an ID, stick that in the array instead. If there's a page template instead you'll need `is_page_template()` instead of is_page